# Flutter, is a bad practice passing this as argument to Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, and I have this question... If I have a Stateful Widget like this:

```
class LoginScreenState extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> animation;
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  FocusNode focusNodepassword = new FocusNode();
  User user = User();

some more code...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoginScreen(
      xWidgetPosition: animation.value,
      yWidgetPosition: animation.value,
      onRegisterPress: goToRegister,
      onButtonPress: null,
      makePasswordVisible: this.makePasswordVisible,
      isPasswordVisible: this.isPasswordVisible,
      focusNodePassword: this.focusNodepassword,
    );
  }
}
```

is it a bad practice if I change passing every property to just passing "this" to the stateles widget LoginScreen and read the instance properties as state?, Example:

```
class LoginScreenState extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> animation;
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  FocusNode focusNodepassword = new FocusNode();
  User user = User();

some more code...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoginScreen(
      state: this
    );
  }
}
```

I'm making this to avoid write and pass every property of the stateful widget to the stateless widget when there are too much variables to pass, but I'm worried if is it a bad practice or a poor programing by using this design.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not good practice. One problem that I can see is that once you start holding on to state references like this, you may prevent the garbage collector from destroying some state objects. I cannot think of any other specific issues this may cause, though.

You are better off using something like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Comment: Maybe you are right, thanks for the recomendation  I'll check it out!